# Can "than" be used at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-starts

I am reading "Eureka - A prose poem", but I find that a strange sentence (for me):

> **"Than the persons"** -- the letter goes on to say -- **"than the persons
>   thus suddenly elevated by the Hog-ian philosophy into a station for
>   which they were unfitted** -- thus transferred from the sculleries into
>   the parlors of Science -- from its pantries into its pulpits -- **than
>   these individuals a more intolerant** -- a more intolerable set of
>   bigots and tyrants never existed on the face of the earth.- "Eureka - A prose poem" | Edgar Allan Poe

I do not understand the meaning of "than" in this sentence, especially in "than these individuals a more intolerant". Can "than" be used at the beginning of sentence? What is "than these individuals a more intolerant" exactly meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this flourish is a [sentence inversion](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-sentence-inversion/). A simpler construction of the sentence would be

> A more intolerable set of bigots and tyrants never existed on the face of the earth than the persons thus suddenly elevated by the Hog-ian philosophy into a station for which they were unfitted